# Regex in haskell to find all occurrences of a pattern in a String

Tags: regex, haskell

I am trying to find occurrences of a particular pattern in a string and have written the regex for the same. But the output is different when using different method in haskell.
Pasting a sample for reference

Regex

`<nARD>([a-zA-Z0-9?=-]*)</nARD>`

Input String

`<a> <b> <nARD>abcd</nARD> </c> <nARD>pqrs</nARD>`

Expected Output

`["abcd","pqrs"]`

Current Output when using `(getAllTextMatches (fileData =~ "<nARD>([a-zA-Z0-9?=-]*)</nARD>") :: [String])` operator

`["<nARD>abcd</nARD>","<nARD>pqrs</nARD>"]`

Current output when using `matchRegex` function

`matchRegex (mkRegex "<nARD>([a-zA-Z0-9?=-]*)</nARD>") "<a> <b> <nARD>abcd</nARD> </c> <nARD>pqrs</nARD>"`

Output

`Just ["abcd"]`

but expected output is `Just ["abcd","pqrs"]`

Comment: Apparently all regex-like things in haskell follow a very polymorphic API (not intuitive in my opinion). Instead of writing `string =~ regex` try this `string =~ regex :: [[String]]`

Comment: Also, take into account that your regex actually matches  `["<nARD>abcd</nARD>","<nARD>pqrs</nARD>"]` but you are not interested in the matches, but in the _matching groups_, which is different.

Comment: @Ismor I think the return type is supposed to be of type [String] i.e. list of string. Can you help me with getting the matching groups? Or point me to some documentation which can help with the same?

Comment: which regex library are you using?? I am assuming `regex-tdfa`

Comment: @Ismor Yes, I was using regex-tdfa. Have now moved to ```regex-pcre``` and your suggestion worked Thanks. Can you also help me figure out how to include ```*``` as one of the characters to be matched between <nARD> and </nARD>?? Basically I want the regex to work on this as well
<nARD> 1234****</nARD> should also match

Comment: [Zal*go* **com̡e̶** s.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/791604)

Comment: @lsmor regex-applicative is my favorite regex library, and it doesn't have the hugely-polymorphic problem. It does have the "problem" that you write a regex in parsec style, rather than by pasting a blob of PCRE text, but this is a lot more readable and composable, so i recommend it unless your main use case is porting already-written PCRE regexes.

Comment: I am not a regex expert so I can't help you further than this. Following @amalloy's suggestion, If you are not porting software already written with regex, I'd strongly recommend using something like `attoparsec` or any kind of applicative parser library. They are way easier and readable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Find all occurrences of string patterns with https://hackage.haskell.org/package/replace-megaparsec

```hs
import Data.Void
import Replace.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char
import Data.Either

input = "<a> <b> <nARD>abcd</nARD> </c> <nARD>pqrs</nARD>"

pattern :: Parsec Void String String
pattern = do
    string "<nARD>"
    fst <$> anyTill (string "</nARD>")

rights $ splitCap pattern input
```

---

```hs
["abcd","pqrs"]
```